# 3 Band Crossover with Linkwitz Riley Filter

Tags: filters, phase, allpass

I would like to write a 3 Band "EQ" with BiQuad Filters but for some reason, I get some phase distortion.

The problem already got discussed [here](http://www.dsprelated.com/showmessage/112896/1.php).

I found out that I need to work with Allpass filters in order to compensate the phase response of my filters. Btw, the filters are Linkwitz-Riley 2nd order filters.

But when I try to copy the idea to my project, I still have some distortion.

```
// low pass calcuation for linkwitz riley filters

float lowCutoff; // the lower cutoff frequency
float highCutoff; // the higher cutoff frequency

double omega = M_PI * cutoffFrequency;  
double theta = omega / sampleRate;
double kappa = omega / tan(theta);
double delta = kappa * kappa + omega * omega + 2.0 * kappa * omega;

double a0 = (omega * omega) / delta;
double a1 = 2.0 * a0;
double a2 = a0;

double b1 = (-2.0 * kappa * kappa + 2.0 * omega * omega) / delta;
double b2 = (-2.0 * kappa * omega + kappa * kappa + omega * omega) / delta;

// high pass, only the calculation of a0 to b2 changes
// the intermediate values stay the same

double a0 = (kappa * kappa) / delta;
double a1 = -2.0 * a0;
double a2 = a0;

double b1 = (-2.0 * kappa * kappa + 2.0 * omega * omega) / delta;
double b2 = (-2.0 * kappa * omega + kappa * kappa + omega * omega) / delta;

// allpass filter to compensate phase response:

double q = 0.5;
double alpha = (tan(M_PI*q/sampleRate) - 1) / (tan(M_PI*0.5/sampleRate) + 1);
double beta =   -cos(lowCutoff  * M_PI / sampleRate);

double a0 = -alpha;
double a1 = beta*(1.0 - alpha);
double a2 = 1.0;
double b1 = beta*(1.0 - alpha);;
double b2 = -alpha;;
```

Since I use 2nd order filters, I also have to use a 2nd order all pass filter, right?
I've read that for those filters and with this calculation, I hav to use `q`. So `q` should be the same as the `q` in the Linkwitz-Riley filter, which should be `0.5` right? (I've read this somewhere, not sure about it.)

Then, my actual processing looks something like this:

```
// filter names:
// loAPF, lowHPF, ... low: lower cutoffhigh: higher cutoff
// APF: allpass, HPF: highpass, LPF: lowpass

highSample =  lowAPF->tick(highHPF->tick(sample));
midSample =   lowHPF->tick(highLPF->tick(sample));
lowSample =   lowLPF->tick(highLPF->tick(sample));
```

Does somebody have any idea, why I might have problems with the phase response?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just noticed that I used the high lowpass filtertwice, which isn't realy how you use dgital filters. :/
So this could be a problem but looking over, I also think that the phases are still off or not 360° shifted to each other.

Comment: a LRF shouldnt have a Q value at all...

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the points made in the question. 
Besides that, LRFs are put together usually with 2nd order IIR filters (cascaded) and thus have internal Q coefficients. They're however fixed by the design assumption that the sum of two filters (LP, HP) should have a flat cross over.

So, A LRF doesn't have a parametric Q like a generic 2nd order lowpass. But it still has a Q parameter that is defined by the design assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reference at the [Linkwitz website](http://www.linkwitzlab.com/crossovers.htm) regarding the *"The Duelund 3-way crossover filter function D3"* that appears to be the 3-band that is **not** derived from splitting one band of a 2-band L-R crossover.  I may have seen this before, but I am not familiar.  I'll look at it now and see if I can grok it.

Here's [another reference](http://www.musicanddesign.com/Duelund_and_Beyond.html) to the Duelund thingie.

Okay, it appears that this is the essential Duelund 3-way crossover:

$$ H_\text{LP}(s) = \frac{1}{s^4 + 2as^3 + (a^2+2)s^2 + 2as + 1} $$

$$ H_\text{BP}(s) = \frac{-(a^2+2)s^2}{s^4 + 2as^3 + (a^2+2)s^2 + 2as + 1} $$

$$ H_\text{HP}(s) = \frac{s^4}{s^4 + 2as^3 + (a^2+2)s^2 + 2as + 1} $$

and this all adds up to an All-pass filter.  Looks like $a=2\sqrt2$ is recommended.

Comment: and here's a link to the [original Dueland article](http://www.diy-audio.narod.ru/litr/duelund-filter.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

A 2nd-order Linkwitz-Riley crossover needs 1st-order allpass phase compensation.

The Lowpass half of the LR crossover is:

$$\dfrac{1}{s^2+2s+1} $$

The Highpass half of the LR crossover is:

$$\dfrac{s^2}{s^2+2s+1} $$

With even-order LR crossovers, in order to sum-to-allpass one of the two sections has to have inverted polarity. Thus:

$$\dfrac{s^2}{s^2 + 2s +1} - \dfrac{1}{s^2 + 2s +1}= \dfrac{(s-1)(s+1)}{(s+1)(s+1)} = \dfrac{(s-1)}{(s+1)}$$

Comment: Could you do me the favor and add some link which explaines what what 1/ (s²...) stands for? I sadly have no clue was `s` is and what the term means. ;D

I've used 4th order and a 2nd order APF, which worked. But knowing how to solve this for 2nd order LR filters would be nice! :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform